# How to find out process that uses file but is not using at the moment?

Tags: macos, mac, bash, audio, process

### Background

I, as well as many other people according to Apple's support forums, am having some trouble with the audio settings on my Mac. Whenever the computer sleeps or powers off, the audio resets to the internal speakers and the system won't recognise what is plugged in the audio jack. Resetting NVRAM or the SMC will fix the problem until the machine either sleeps or gets powered off, when the problem will persist.

### The Idea

Turns out that deleting the following files:

- `/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.DeviceSettings.plist`
- `/Library/Preferences/Audio/com.apple.audio.SystemSettings.plist`

And then rebooting will also do the temporary fix, but then again, that requires rebooting. My idea is to write a bash script that `rm`s both files and then kills the process that uses them. The problem however is to find out what process loads them. Unfortunately `lsof` doesn't work, cause the process doesn't use them constantly, they get loaded when the process starts and thats it.

### The Question

How would I find out which process is loading the files everytime I reboot, given that the process doesn't keep constant access to the file and that it might be loading them before login?

*Bonus points if you have had this problem on your Mac before and knows how to fix it.*

Answer (score 2):

*NIXes have daemon called "audit". You can set this daemon to watch for any chnages to the files:

MAN:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/audit.8.html

It's OpenBSM and here is some more information about it:

http://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/01/30/openbsm-auditing-on-mac-os-x/

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more on how would I use `audit` to accomplish this? I read the *man* and did some research but this tool seems to be awfully complicated.